# UITableView not displaying the correct number of rows

Tags: swift, uitableview, core-data, swift3, nsfetchrequest

I have a problem with my cellForRow at index path function and I cannot spot it sadly. So i am turning to the kind people of this establishment. 
I perform a fetch request that returns the results array of type Floors (which is my entity). I only have one section in table and the result is only one row. If i declare 5 floors I get only one row with the text value of "4". it is always the value that I have declared - 1. Could someone please have a look at my code and help me spot the problem? Thank you and kind regards.

```
class AssignNumberOfRoomsForFloorsVC: UITableViewController {

//MARK: - Properties

private var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext!

private var storedFloors = [Floors]()


//MARK: - Actions

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
    loadFloorData()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

private func loadFloorData() {
    let request: NSFetchRequest<Floors> = Floors.fetchRequest()
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
    do {
        storedFloors = try managedObjectContext.fetch(request)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
    catch {
        print("could not load data from core \(error.localizedDescription)")

    }
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return storedFloors.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "floor cell", for: indexPath) as! FloorCell
    let floorItem = storedFloors[indexPath.row]
    cell.floorNumberTxt.text = String(floorItem.floorNumber)
    return cell
}
```

this code is used to set up the number of floor:

```
 @IBAction private func setTheNumberOfFloors(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let house = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "House", into: managedObjectContext) as! House
    house.numberOfFloors = floorNumberValue
    print(" the number of floors in the house is: \(house)")

    loadFloorData()
    for floor in storedFloors {
        for i in 0...floor.numberOfFloors - 1 {
            let instance = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Floors", into: managedObjectContext) as! Floors
            instance.floorNumber = i
            print("\(instance)")
            house.addToFloors(instance)
        }
    }
 private func loadFloorData() {
    let request = NSFetchRequest<House>(entityName: "House")
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
    do {
        storedFloors = try managedObjectContext.fetch(request)
    }
    catch {
        print("could not load data from core \(error.localizedDescription)")

    }
}
```

Comment: It's all up to this line: `storedFloors = try managedObjectContext.fetch(request)`. If that is giving the wrong results than you need to figure out why.

Comment: Thank you.  I can see the number of Floors object created in the print and it is correct. what i am using to set the number of floors is in the edited question section code listing

Comment: there is definitely something wrong there but I cannot spot it. if you wouldn't mind to have a look please

Comment: i partially fixed it. i just put the entity description init in the loop. I do get the correct number of rows but not in the correct order. for 3 floors i get 0 2 1. Could anyone please point me as to why is this happening? Thank you

Comment: Can you try moving the reload call self.tableView.reloadData() from loadFloorData() and put in viewDidLoad after the loadFloorData() call.

Comment: no effect. still the same unordered rows

Comment: If you want the floor items in a specific order, shouldn't you be ordering them when you fetch the Floor items? I don't believe I see any sorting happening, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Fahim said, you need to set a sort descriptor for the fetch used to display the table:

```
request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: #keyPath(Floors.floorNumber), ascending: true)]
```

Also, make sure to save the moc after inserting new entities or making any modifications:

```
        do {
            try managedObjectContext.save()
        } catch {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            let nserror = error as NSError
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
        }
```

Or, if you're using the standard generated code:

```
UIApplication.shared.delegate.saveContext()
```